# How do I determine why a Bootstrap 5 Modal button is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have a Django based web site that uses bootstrap 5. I have a table of data and a notes column with a lot of text. I am trying to use the Bootstrap Modal popup feature to display the notes to keep the table smaller. The long notes text makes the table hard to read. When I say long notes, I mean about 15-25 words.

When I click the button "Read the notes", the modal does not appear.

My html:

```
    {% for f in flights %}
      {% for flight in f.flight_data %}
            <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="{{ flight.flight_id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="{{ flight.flight_id }}Label" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="{{ flight.flight_id }}Label">Notes for the flight of the {{ flight.name }}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                {{ flight.notes|safe }}
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   
    {% for f in flights %}
      <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-header pb-0">
              <p class="mb-1 pt-2 text-bold">{{ f.date }}</p>
              <h5 class="font-weight-bolder">{{ f.teacher_name }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body px-0 pt-0 pb-2">
              <div class="table-responsive p-0">
                <table class="display" id="models" style="width:100%">
                  <thead>
                  <tr class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold">
                      <th rowspan="2">Rocket Name</th>
                      <th rowspan="2">Mission Specialists</th>
                      <th rowspan="2">Flight Engineers</th>
                      <th rowspan="2">Type</th>
                      <th colspan="1">Lift-off Weight</th>
                      <th colspan="2">Altitude</th>
                      <th rowspan="2">Egg</th>
                      <th rowspan="2">Shockcord</th>
                      <th rowspan="2">Nose cone</th>
                      <th rowspan="2">Coupler</th>
                      <th rowspan="2">Parachute</th>
                      <th rowspan="2">Notes</th>
                  </tr>
                    <tr class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold">
                      <th>grams</th>
                      <th>meters</th>
                      <th>feet</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  {%  for flight in f.flight_data %}
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold">{{ flight.name }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.mission_specialists }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.flight_engineers }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.rocket_type }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.weight|format_zero|format_data:1|units:'g' }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.altitude_m|format_zero|format_data:1|units:'m' }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.altitude_f|format_zero|format_data:1|units:'ft' }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.egg }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.shockcord }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.nose_cone }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.coupler }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.parachute }}</td>
                      <!--<td class="mb-4 text-lg font-weight-bold">{{ flight.notes|safe }}</td>-->
                      <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap"> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{ flight.flight_id }}">Read the flight notes</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  {% endfor %}    
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

The rendered html:

```
   <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="629" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="629Label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="629Label">Notes for the flight of the Baseball Boys and Ellie</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        We used tissues and 4 cotton balls to cushion the egg. Our predicted altitude was 500 feet. The rocket took off and arced over toward the southeast. The parachute came out and the rocket was spinning a lot as it came down. The wind pushed the rocket over the fence and it landed on the sidewalk. <a href="https://hopirockets.com/gallery_rockets/index.php/Jan_9_2023/Voris/Baseball_Boys_and_Ellie" target="_blank">Pictures</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  
<div class="row mt-4">
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="card mb-4">
    <div class="card-header pb-0">
      <p class="mb-1 pt-2 text-bold">01/09/2023</p>
      <h5 class="font-weight-bolder">Mrs. Voris</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body px-0 pt-0 pb-2">
      <div class="table-responsive p-0">
        <table class="display" id="models" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
          <tr class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold">
              <th rowspan="2">Rocket Name</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Mission Specialists</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Flight Engineers</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Type</th>
              <th colspan="1">Lift-off Weight</th>
              <th colspan="2">Altitude</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Egg</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Shockcord</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Nose cone</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Coupler</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Parachute</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Notes</th>
          </tr>
            <tr class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold">
              <th>grams</th>
              <th>meters</th>
              <th>feet</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold">Baseball Boys and Ellie</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">Jackson</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">Sol, Ellie</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">Astra III</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">91.2 g</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">97.0 m</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">318.3 ft</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">intact</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">intact</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">intact</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">intact</td>
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">opened</td>
              <!--<td class="mb-4 text-lg font-weight-bold">We used tissues and 4 cotton balls to cushion the egg. Our predicted altitude was 500 feet. The rocket took off and arced over toward the southeast. The parachute came out and the rocket was spinning a lot as it came down. The wind pushed the rocket over the fence and it landed on the sidewalk. <a href="https://hopirockets.com/gallery_rockets/index.php/Jan_9_2023/Voris/Baseball_Boys_and_Ellie" target="_blank">Pictures</a></td>-->
              <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap"> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#629">Read the flight notes</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I verified that bootstrap.min.js and popper.min.js are loaded on the page.

I tried putting the Modal divs in the "td" that has the button, but it did not work there either.

Where do the Modal divs go on a page?

A picture of this part of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, it seems in bootstrap 5+, some names were changed...to  protect the innocent, perhaps??

```
data-toggle -> data-bs-toggle
data-target -> data-bs-target
data-dismiss -> data-bs-dismiss
```

With these changes, my code worked. Except for an error when I tried to use a numerical id. I added a prefix of 'modal' in front of the id, and it all works now.

Comment: Yes, IDs cannot be numbers at the start https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp#:~:text=Note%3A%20The%20id%20name%20must,%2C%20tabs%2C%20etc.). I remember a bit ago running into this